# cv::MatchShapes behaves differently for iOS deployment target - 8.0 vs 9.0 or 10.0

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I'm having a very interesting issue with OpenCV and different deployment targets, and I'm running out of ideas of what to try.

**Setup**

- iPhone 6S
- iOS Version 10.1.1
- OpenCV framework  3.1.0.1
- XCode 8.1

**Problem**

When I compile my code with my Deployment Target(in Xcode) set to 8.0, my code works perfectly.

However, when I compile my code with Deployment Target set to 9.0 or 10.0, my code runs but the values I receive from `matchShapes` is completely different.

Everything seems to be running fine - I do some filtering before `matchShapes`, and the output from all the filters are perfect. It seems like it's just specifically `matchShapes` that's the issue.

There are no additional warnings at buildtime when I switch deployment targets.

**Attempted Solutions**

1. I updated everything and made sure it's at the latest version
2. I tried downloading `openCV.framework` and using the OpenCV pod

**Code**

This is the line of code of interest:

```
double matchPercentage = cv::matchShapes(targetShape.contour, contours[i], CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0);
```

**Question For You**

Any suggestions or ideas for what might cause this? Happy to run any sort of additional diagnostics or testing and report back.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do you use pod for OpenCV? What version?

Comment: I downloaded the latest 3.2.0 framework for iOS from here http://opencv.org/releases.html